# Error krb5_get_init_creds client unknown al unir máquina Debian a dominio Zentyal

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, dominio

Esta es mi configuración de red:

- /etc/network/interfaces.d/

  ````
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback ```

  ```  #The primary network interface
    auto ens18
    iface ens18 inet static
    address 172.26.27.139
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 172.26.0.1
    broadcast 172.26.255.255
    gateway 172.26.0.1
    dns-domain pepito.local
    dns-search pepito.local ```
  ````
- /etc/resolv.conf

  `nameserver 172.26.27.130 (Apunta al controlador Zentyal)`

Ahora inserto la configuración de krb5:

```
default_realm = jncb.local
rnds = no
dns_lookup-kc = true
dns_lookup_realm = false
```

Una vez vista mi configuración para unir mi Debian (172.26.27.139) al controlador de dominio Zentyal (172.27.27.139) intento unirme con un usuario administrador de tal manera:

```
kinit pepito
```

> pepito@pepito.local's Password:

*Introduzco la contraseña correcta*

> krb5_get_init_creds client (pepito@pepito.local unknown

Para dar más detalles facilito los nombres de dominio:

Zentyal: pepito.local
cliente "/etc/hosts": pepito2.pepito.local pepito2

Tanto como el servidor y cliente hacen ping a internet y entre ellos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que descargase el siguiente script, dar permisos y ejecutarlo para resolver el problema:

> https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/releases/download/9.1.0/pbis-open-9.1.0.551.linux.x86_64.deb.sh

Cuando lo descarguemos, le damos permiso:

> chmod 751 pbis-open-9.1.0.551.linux.x86_64.deb.sh

Comprobamos los permisos:

> ls -la

Entonces nos unimos desactivando ssh para evitar errores:

> opt/pbis/domainjoin-cli join --disable pepito.local pepitox (cualquier usuario del dominio Zentyal)

Luego os pedirá la contraseña del usuario a conectarse y si la habéis introducido correctamente tendréis que reiniciar en caso de que sea la primera vez.